# How to create a backup database in sql azure using as copy of option and setting edition with max size at the same time

Tags: sql, t-sql, azure-sql-database

I've been using the code below:

```
CREATE DATABASE [NSFKIPRODDB01_BKBK] AS COPY OF [NSFKIPRODDB01] (EDITION='BUSINESS', MAXSIZE = 10GB)
```

But it keeps on throwing me the error below:

```
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near 'AS'.
```

Comment: Perhaps because the documentation [states](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ee336274.aspx) that "AS COPY OF cannot be used with any other CREATE DATABASE arguments"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can I ask why isn't a CREATE DATABASE AS COPY OF + ALTER DATABASE good enough?